# Basic Hosting Postgresql in Virtualbox + Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, postgresql

I have configured Postgres to accept network connections from anywhere:

In `pg_hga.conf`:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

In `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I can see the server is listening:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address     Foreign Address   State    PID/Program name
<snip>
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5433      0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN   1570/postgres
```

I've configured iptables to allow incoming TCP connections to 5433:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5433

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

From an ssh session in the VM, I can run `telnet 10.0.2.15 5433` and it works. I can also connect with the full psql client. From my host, if I run the same telnet command or the same psql command, I can't connect.

What can be wrong and what can I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network adapter of your VM is by default in NAT mode. This means you can't ssh/telnet/etc to you VM from outside of it. Switch to Bridged in the VM settings and it should work.